# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

I am about to calculate average of four textbox value and assign it to a label, but this 
error come up. Not sure what is the real problems. Here is my code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label17.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text)) / 4).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: check my answer and tell me if something is not clear !

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2)`

...should be:

`Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text)`

Comment: hi.thanks.I have corrected it, but another error come up:
 Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @newbie_pro - Then ask another question - don't put it in a comment of another answer.

Comment: @newbie_pro you didn't fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal value1 = 0;
        decimal value2 = 0;
        decimal value3 = 0;
        decimal value4 = 0;

        decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1);
        decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2);
        decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out value3);
        decimal.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out value4);

        label17.Text = ((value1+value2+value3+value4)/4).ToString()
    }
```

You miss `textbox2.Text` in one of the converts. Also the converts will return an error if the format value of the Text is not number(**Example** if I write `'123a'`). Because of that you should use `TryParse` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks! i tried this one but for decimal.TryParse(textBox11.Text, value1); got error, it said has some invalid arguments.Any help?..

Comment: It should be `decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1);` - you're missing the `out` keyword.